# Can't use localhost version of glassfish 4.1 server on eclipse Luna

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish

Maybe someone will know how to solve my small issue with J2EE. I have glassfish 4.1 server installed on my mac. I have a domain with login and password, I also enabled sequre admin. So and I can start domain through terminal, but when I configure this domain in eclipse (Luna) it always says that my domain is stopped. Can't deploy my J2EE applications because of this problem.

When I press Start in eclipse (even though local glassfish server is already running, because it says Stopped all the time) it start the process, does something till 69%, stays for 5 - 10 min and the gives timeout error.

At the same time in eclipse I configure domain from VPS server where I also have glassfish 4.1 and in this case everything properly works: I can deploy J2EE application to VPS server. The thing is that I want to develop them locally on my mac and only at the end I need to deploy them in VPS.

[image]

Here are logs, but they are not that useful because initially eclipse show wrongly that server is Stopped when it is actually running. And this logs I get after I press Start anyway.

```
2015-04-18T23:36:16.923-0700|Info: Running GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1  (build 13)
2015-04-18T23:36:16.926-0700|Info: Server log file is using Formatter class: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter
2015-04-18T23:36:17.087-0700|Info: Realm [admin-realm] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
2015-04-18T23:36:17.089-0700|Info: Realm [file] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
2015-04-18T23:36:17.095-0700|Info: Realm [certificate] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm] successfully created.
2015-04-18T23:36:17.337-0700|Info: Authorization Service has successfully initialized.
2015-04-18T23:36:17.411-0700|Info: Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry
2015-04-18T23:36:17.657-0700|Info: Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 45ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8080]
2015-04-18T23:36:17.909-0700|Info: Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 2ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]
2015-04-18T23:36:17.947-0700|Info: Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 2ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:4848]
2015-04-18T23:36:18.023-0700|Info: Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 2ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:3700]
2015-04-18T23:36:18.025-0700|Info: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1  (13) startup time : Felix (2,861ms), startup services(1,215ms), total(4,076ms)
2015-04-18T23:36:18.229-0700|Info: Creating a SecureRMIServerSocketFactory @ 0.0.0.0 with ssl config = GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.grizzly.config.dom.Ssl
2015-04-18T23:36:18.236-0700|Info: SSLParams =org.glassfish.admin.mbeanserver.ssl.SSLParams@683f4133
2015-04-18T23:36:18.236-0700|Warning: All SSL cipher suites disabled for network-listener(s).  Using SSL implementation specific defaults
2015-04-18T23:36:18.355-0700|Info: SSLParams =org.glassfish.admin.mbeanserver.ssl.SSLParams@683f4133
2015-04-18T23:36:18.355-0700|Warning: All SSL cipher suites disabled for network-listener(s).  Using SSL implementation specific defaults
2015-04-18T23:36:18.450-0700|Info: Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 2ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:7676]
2015-04-18T23:36:18.453-0700|Info: Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@178270b2 as OSGi service registration: org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl@7573e12f.
2015-04-18T23:36:18.924-0700|Info: visiting unvisited references
2015-04-18T23:36:19.096-0700|Info: SSLServerSocket /0.0.0.0:8686 and [SSL: ServerSocket[addr=/0.0.0.0,localport=8686]] created
2015-04-18T23:36:19.384-0700|Info: JMXStartupService has started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://192.168.0.6:8686/jndi/rmi://192.168.0.6:8686/jmxrmi
2015-04-18T23:36:19.908-0700|Info: HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.0.0.Final
2015-04-18T23:36:20.406-0700|Info: Created HTTP listener http-listener-1 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8080
2015-04-18T23:36:20.421-0700|Info: Created HTTP listener http-listener-2 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8181
2015-04-18T23:36:20.427-0700|Info: Created HTTP listener admin-listener on host/port 0.0.0.0:4848
2015-04-18T23:36:20.477-0700|Info: Created virtual server server
2015-04-18T23:36:20.481-0700|Info: Created virtual server __asadmin
2015-04-18T23:36:20.935-0700|Info: Setting JAAS app name glassfish-web
2015-04-18T23:36:20.936-0700|Info: Virtual server server loaded default web module 
2015-04-18T23:36:21.386-0700|Info: Java security manager is disabled.
2015-04-18T23:36:21.387-0700|Info: Entering Security Startup Service.
2015-04-18T23:36:21.392-0700|Info: Loading policy provider com.sun.enterprise.security.provider.PolicyWrapper.
2015-04-18T23:36:21.454-0700|Info: Security Service(s) started successfully.
2015-04-18T23:36:21.842-0700|Info: visiting unvisited references
2015-04-18T23:36:21.878-0700|Info: visiting unvisited references
2015-04-18T23:36:21.885-0700|Info: visiting unvisited references
2015-04-18T23:36:23.663-0700|Info: Initializing Mojarra 2.2.7 ( 20140610-1547 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.7@13362) for context ''
2015-04-18T23:36:26.111-0700|Info: Loading application [__admingui] at [/]
2015-04-18T23:36:26.113-0700|Info: Loading application __admingui done in 7,874 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

fixed this problem by reinstalling eclipse. I mean I even uninstalled Eclipse Luna completely and downloaded and installed Ecplise Kepler.

So now I have two servers that I can use either local or VPS.